# FFmpeg input issue

Tags: ffmpeg, exec, shell-exec

I'm trying to re size a video that's not in the same directory of PHP exec code, this is my ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i ../Gotten Movies/test.mp4 -s hd480 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 ../Gotten Movies/test2o.mp4
```

The error which I'm getting is: `../Gotten: Invalid data found when processing input` I think the problem is because of choosing previous directory with ../ I've tried to

```
cd Gotten Movies; ffmpeg.exe -i ../Gotten Movies/test.mp4 -s hd480 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 ../Gotten Movies/test2o.mp4
```

But it didn't work too what can shall I do to fix the issue thanks.

Comment: Use \ instead of /

Comment: same problem its showing `..\Gotten: Invalid data found when processing input` now :(

Comment: thanks you its working now make it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always safer to enclose paths with special characters in quotes:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "../Gotten Movies/test.mp4" -s hd480 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -strict -2 "../Gotten Movies/test2o.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI:
Windows is **really** picky on single vs double quotes.
I input my file like this in the PHP (this escapes word spaces in filenames and directories):

```
$filepath=$file->getPath();
$filepath=str_replace('\\',"/",$filepath);
$filename='abc.mpg';
```

pass them in *separately* to my function - then do this:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "'.$filePath.'"/"'.$fileName.'" 2>&1 | findstr Duration';
$data = exec($cmd, $output);
```

if there is an error $output will contain full response with errors - otherwise $data gives the item I want  (Duration)